# crypt on MacOS and DEBIAN different results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, macos, debian, crypt

I'm using ruby-on-rails for my backend, and I'm having problem with crypt.

I'm trying to make sure the result after running 'crypt' is the same on MacOS and Debian. However, couldn't find the way yet.

So, here is the example. If I run this on MacOS and Debian, I get different result:

```
"asdfasdf".crypt("$1$hahahoho")

# OSX:    "$1dE4R/8VUBi2"
# DEBIAN: "$1$hahahoho$4r6RNehw5Vj9O/.sISq9S1"
```

DEBIAN has the correct answer, though.

Is there any way I can make OSX to crypt properly?

Comment: `man 3 crypt` should help you along.

Comment: Srry... I'm a noob... I didn't get what you mean by that. You mean the crypt command from terminal?